# Placing a swap function at the end of the file makes it work

Tags: c++, function, swap

I have a program that swaps two numbers:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap(int a, int b) {
    int temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

int main() {
    int a, b;

    cout << "Enter the first number: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter the second number: ";
    cin >> b;

    cout << "Before swapping, the first number was " << a << ", and the second was " << b << "." << endl;

    swap(a, b);

    cout << "After swapping, the first number is " << a << ", and the second is " << b << "." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
Enter the first number: 1
Enter the second number: 3
Before swapping, the first number was 1, and the second was 3.
After swapping, the first number is 1, and the second is 3.
```

Which is expected, since the `swap` function modifies the variables `a` and `b` within the function, and that should have no impact on their values in the `main` function.

However, if I place the `swap` function after the `main` function, without a function prototype, the swap ACTUALLY takes place:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a, b;

    cout << "Enter the first number: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter the second number: ";
    cin >> b;

    cout << "Before swapping, the first number was " << a << ", and the second was " << b << "." << endl;

    swap(a, b);

    cout << "After swapping, the first number is " << a << ", and the second is " << b << "." << endl;

    return 0;
}

void swap(int a, int b) {
    int temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

The above produces the following output:

```
Enter the first number: 1
Enter the second number: 3
Before swapping, the first number was 1, and the second was 3.
After swapping, the first number is 3, and the second is 1.
```

Why does this happen? Could anyone please explain?

Comment: [`using namespace std;` is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for this reason.  You are mixing standard library functions with your own functions, and you are having difficulty tracking which function is being called.  Remove that line.

Comment: You swap operates on copies of the numbers, caller a, b are not affected. Use references swap(int& a, int& b)

Comment: [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)

Comment: This is an excellent post containing an excellent (and pretty much real-world) example of the importance of namespaces and avoiding `using namespace`. I hope

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux, the asker was already fully aware of how their swap function operates, as evidenced in their sentence beginning _"Which is expected, since..."_

Comment: One difference between this example and the identified duplicate is that `std::swap()` is allowed - but not required - to be declared in `<iostream>`.   If `std::swap()` is not declared then defining the `swap(int, int)` after `main()` is a diagnosable error, since no `swap()` is declared before its first use in `main()`.   So the code as given works as described with some toolchains, but won't compile with others.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `using namespace std` is discouraged, and your case is an example illustrating why. When your `swap` function comes after `main()`, `main()` uses `std::swap` and not your `swap`.

Although `std::swap` has an impact outside its local scope, your custom `swap` has no impact outside its local scope. In order to have an impact, `a` and `b` should be passed by reference.

```cpp
#include <iostream>


void swap(int& a, int& b) // (In order to have an impact: 'a' and 'b' hould be passed by reference) 
{
    int temp;

    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}


int main() 
{
    int a, b;

    std::cout << "Enter the first number: ";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "Enter the second number: ";
    std::cin >> b;

    std::cout << "Before swapping, the first number was " << a << ", and the second was " << b << "." << std::endl;

    swap(a, b);

    std::cout << "After swapping, the first number is " << a << ", and the second is " << b << "." << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/6jd9ivk4s)

Answer (score 1):

> if I place the swap function after the main function, without a function prototype, the swap ACTUALLY takes place [...]
>
> Why does this happen? Could anyone please explain?

That's because it's not *your* `swap` function that's being used but instead `std::swap`.

You can test this by removing `using namespace std;` or by naming your function `MySwap` and provide a prototype to it before `main`. Your swap function will not swap the values in the caller's variables no matter where you place it.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your function at the end of the file, it remains as broken as at the beginning of the file. The difference is that if you put it at the end of the file, it never gets called. A different function, the standard one `std::swap` gets called instead.

That's what happens when you use `using namespace std`. You get a totally different function silently called instead of the one you intended, and scratch your head until cows come home. [Never use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

As for your function, you shouldn't actually use it because the standard function exists and does a better job. Still you want to understand why it is broken. For that, you need to understand what is pass by value, how it is different from pass by reference, and how and when to use either. A good C++ textbook should cover this topic.